# Using Angular to get html of a website URL

Tags: html, angular, http

I am new in Angular 
What I am going to try is to get the HTML of a page and reproduce it into an iFrame (it is an exercise). 
I am using the following piece of code:

```
    var prova = this._http.get(myUrl, {responseType: "text"}).subscribe((x) =>{
  console.log(x);
});
```

I did it on a website (if is needed I can also insert the name of the pages) and it returns the html only of some pages. 
In the other case the string x is empty. 
Could it depend on connection? 
Or there is some way to wait the end of the get request? 
Or simply is wrong my approach and I should make a different type of request?

Comment: Is myUrl a static html page?

Comment: no 
are list and product pages of an ecommerce

Comment: Your going to run into various issues due to java script not executing on the page you are trying to get. I would suggesting test your code on a static web page first.

Comment: tried on static webpages and it works. If your supposition is right what could I do? could be a request header problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Your most likely going to need to use a library like puppeteer if you want to render a page properly. Puppeteer is a node library and useless headless chrome so I am not sure how well you could really integrate with Angular.

https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: ok I'll try to integrate the library in my project (I think is enough to add as "script" into angular.json). Thanks